# Can you put small electronics with a battery in checked luggage on EU flights?

Tags: luggage, eu

I have an electric shaver with a built in battery. Can I put it in my checked luggage on EU flights?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

According to the [IATA guidelines](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Documents/passenger-lithium-battery.pdf), you can have up to 15 personal electronic devices with a built-in lithium-ion battery that has a capacity of less than 100 Wh, which should be the case of an electric shaver battery, either in your carry-on or as checked luggage, without operator approval.

Spare batteries and batteries of higher capacities are subject to different rules.

If carried in checked baggage, "***measures must be taken to protect the device from damage and to prevent unintentional activation***".

You may still want to check your airlines rules, though as far as I know, most if not all follow IATA guidelines.